MSSQL on AWS: remote user unable to establish connection via SSMS
Newly created MSSQL 2017 SE instance, using SQL authentication. I am able to connect to it with no issues via my corporate VPN. Overseas user on VPN is unable to connect, getting this error from SSMS:
Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=979; handshake=29695;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

Azure Data Studio gets a similar error.
The security group was modified to allow their IP address range. Even tried 0.0.0.0/0 as a test, but that didn't help. Tried enabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 but that didn't help either. Using the PowerShell cmdlet test-netconnection, user is able to connect to instance's IP address and port 1433. I'm at a loss.

Do you RDP into an in-network machine after you connect to your work's VPN to run SSMS? Does the overseas user do the same or are they trying to run SSMS on their local machine?

Both on our local machines.
